# Missing "this" pointer in pointer to member function signature

Tags: c++

I am writing a little signal/slot class. the dispatch function takes an instance of a class and a pointer to member of the type of the instance and stores it in a `std::function` with the instance pointer bound to the first parameter with `std::bind` to provide the `this` pointer. My main question is am i misunderstanding the rules of c++, or is my compiler not behaving as expected.

```
template <class Signal, class ... ArgTs>
class SignalDispatcher {
//...
template <class Class>
void dispatch(const Signal& signal, Class* target, void (Class::*slot)(Class*, ArgTs...));
//...
};
```

then if i call the dispatch function with arguments like so

```
SomeStruct instance;
SignalDispatcher<int, some_type> dispatcher;

dispatcher.dispatch(1, &instance, &SomeStruct::member_function);
```

my compiler says the passed member function signature is

```
void (Class::*)(ArgTs...)
```

and not the expected

```
void (Class::*)(Class*, ArgTs...)
```

in turn causing a type mismatch and failure to compile.

my compiler is g++ 6.3.0

Comment: Unless you declare the function so that its first argument is a pointer to some type, there is no reason to expect what you are expecting.

Comment: To get the first parameter as `this` pointer, use `std::mem_fn`

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is right. You don't specify the `this` pointer as a parameter for pointer-to-member. It's provided by the syntax used to define and call it.

```
void (Class::*slot)(ArgTs...);
       ^---- this is a pointer of Class type.

Class c;
(c.*slot)(args...);
 ^--- this will point to c.
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a different syntax for member function pointers for a reason. (A few reasons, but this is one of them.)

As you note, an invisible `this` pointer is passed behind the scenes, but that doesn't mean you need to specify it yourself when passing around member function pointers. The syntax for declaring a member function pointer variable

```
return_type (class_name::*variable_name)(/* arguments */);
```

already has the class name within it. That way the compiler knows what kind of pointer to pass as `this`.

---

Example:

```
struct MyTest
{
    void func1() {}
    int func2(int arg1) { return arg1; }
};

int main()
{
    // One way
    using func1_t = void (MyTest::*)();
    using func2_t = int (MyTest::*)(int);

    func1_t one_func1_ptr = &MyTest::func1;
    func2_t one_func2_ptr = &MyTest::func2;

    // Another way
    void (MyTest::*another_func1_ptr)() = &MyTest::func1;
    int (MyTest::*another_func2_ptr)(int) = &MyTest::func2;

    // Or an easy way (available in some situations)
    auto easy_func1_ptr = &MyTest::func1;
    auto easy_func2_ptr = &MyTest::func2;
}
```